# Ajax.ActionLink not working with htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I have ajax.actionlink in my view defined as:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.sifra_pozicije, //link text
     "UnosuProjekat", // action name
     "Projekti",  // controller
     new { poz = item.sifra_pozicije.ToString(), proj = "Projekat 1" }, // route values
     new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "Projekat" }, // ajax options
     new { @class = "openDialog" } //htmlAttributes
)
```

and generating HTML code

```
<a href="/Projekti/UnosuProjekat?poz=VSG010002&amp;proj=Projekat%201" data-ajax-update="#Projekat" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true" class="openDialog">VSG010002</a>
```

This is sending empty strings to controller action with url request

```
http://localhost:64908/Projekti/UnosuProjekat?_=1397501602503
```

When i remove htmlAttributes from link, HTML stays the same (except class is removed) and parameters are passed to controller.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It is proper that removing htmlattribute will only remove class, the rest of data-* attributes are generated for the functioning of ajax link.

Comment: Css class is opening jqui modal dialog for crud, but i dont know why is affecting parameter values. With css, actionlink send null to controller. Without it, it sends requested values.

Comment: I can only guess if some of your javascript is doing something among the `.openDialog` class. Can you try change the class name to something random and see what's the behaviour?